# Why is TelephonyManager.getCallState() deprecated in Android SDK 31?

Tags: android

An application I work on calls TelephonyManger.getCallState() to find out if the call state is CALL_STATE_IDLE.

Our intention is to avoid distracting the user by opening an activity while a call is in progress.
A courtesy.

However, as of API 31, this call is deprecated:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getCallState()

This method was deprecated in API level 31.
Use getCallStateForSubscription() to retrieve the call state for a specific telephony subscription (which allows carrier privileged apps), TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener for real-time call state updates, or TelecomManager#isInCall(), which supplies an aggregate "in call" state for the entire device.

Worse, it now requires a dangerous and scary permission.
Requires Permission: READ_PHONE_STATE for applications targeting API level 31+.
For any alternatives it suggests - you must either have READ_PHONE_STATE or carrier privileges.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getCallStateForSubscription()

The application I work on does have carrier privileges in some variants, but not all.

But WHY would this be required?

In Behavior changes: Apps targetting Android 12, this change is not mentioned at all:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12

It says nothing whatsoever about the fact that you will no longer be able to tell if a call is in progress.
There is nowhere I can find the reason for this change.

It seems that knowing if user in call is something basic that an app might want to know. Not just apps that have carrier privileges.

Why was it okay for 12 years and suddenly not?

For example, some apps, like Audible, will stop audio when a call comes in and resume when call is completed. So is that not going to happen anymore without dangerous permissions?

READ_PHONE_STATE Permission includes the current cellular network information, the status of any ongoing calls, and a list of any PhoneAccounts registered on the device. A permission which a user will not grant lightly.

Comment: I have the same issue, and also with the PhoneStateListener deprecation.
I saw this issue in the issue tracker, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198331527.
Did you found any solution?

Comment: I am the one who put it in issuetracker, and no solution has been given.

Comment: Just hit same problem. I was checking that to avoid disturbing the users. Did you found any workaround?

Comment: Nope, we're just skipping the check on Android 12. Maybe they won't allow our screen to interrupt a phone call anyway. I just wish there were clarification.